# Simple strange basic python behaviour

Tags: python

Does anybody know why this below code prints 0 and 1 rather than 5 and 2, in csharp similar code would print 5 and 2 and I am just trying to work out the logic here.

```
class Myclass:
    a = 0
    b = 1 

def foo():
    for x in range(1):
        for y in range(1):
            myclass = Myclass()
            if y == 1:
                myclass.a = 5
            if y == 1:
                myclass.b = 2
            ClassList.append(Myclass)

    for x in ClassList:
        print x.a   
        print x.b

ClassList = []
foo()
```

Comment: at the end y=0 cause range(1) returns [0] and x is myclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `range(1)` returns `[0]`, not `[0, 1]`, so your `y == 1` test never evaluates to true.

Also, you're appending `Myclass` rather than `myclass` -- that is, the actual class, rather than the instance you created -- to the list, so you're always printing the unmodified `a` and `b` from the class.

Answer (score 2):

Because `y` is never `1`:

```
>>> range(1)
[0]
```

What you want is `range(2)`

And just incase you are not aware... currently you are using `a` and `b` as class attributes as opposed to instance attributes. For your specific case of doing value assignments, you won't see a problem, but if you were to have defined say, dictionaries or lists, and were changing keys/indices of those objects, it would be the same object shared across all of the instances.

```
class Myclass(object):
    a = []
    b = {}

obj1 = Myclass()
obj2 = Myclass()
obj1.a.append('foo')
obj1.b['biz'] = 'baz'
print obj2.a
# ['foo']
print obj2.b
# {'biz': 'baz'}
```

... vs instance attributes

```
class Myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []
        self.b = {}
```

Comment: "This means settings `myclass.a = 5` will set it for the entire class, shared." <-- This is not true. Evaluating `myclass.a = 5` will always modify the instance's `__dict__`, regardless of whether the name is defined in the class' `__dict__` or not.

Comment: I was just about to delete that. `int` is immutable. If OP were using a list or dict it would matter.

Comment: No, it would still not matter.

Comment: I understand you mean assignments. I am simply pointing out that the OP is using class attributes in case they were not aware. Doing something like `myclass.aDict['foo'] = 'bar'` would be shared among all the instances.

Comment: Sure enough, that is true. Not because `int` is immutable, though.

Comment: But thanks for pointing it out so I realized I needed to rephrase! And immutable being a factor only because there is no way to modify the value of it without losing the class reference.

Comment: Yeah thanks I totally noobed it up. Got it now, thanks for the help.